# How to get generated keys with commons dbutils?

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons, apache-commons-dbutils

I don't understand how to get auto generated keys with commons-dbutils?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`QueryRunner#insert()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/QueryRunner.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.commons.dbutils.ResultSetHandler,%20java.lang.Object...)). Below is an example. Given a table called `users`, which has an auto generated primary key column and a `varchar` column called `username`, you can do something like this:

```
DataSource dataSource = ... // however your app normally gets a DataSource 
QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner(dataSource);
String sql = "insert into users (username) values (?)";
long userId = queryRunner.insert(sql, new ScalarHandler<Long>(), "test");
```

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact I think it cannot be done with the current version of common-dbutils. A few months ago, when I was working for another company, I extented the QueryRunner with my own implementation.

The request has been submitted to the DbUtils project, and there you can even find a viable implementation which I guess you could copy if you really need it.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DBUTILS-54